# Move tables to appendix but keep same in-text numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, appendix

So I'm working on my master's paper and I have a bunch of tables that I'd like to move to an appendix but I'd like to keep the same numbering. So for example, if in text it's referred to as "Table 13", I'd like for it to be numbered Table 13 in the appendix as well.

I have my preamble and a sample table below:

In the paper, this is Table 37; is there a way I can make it so that I move it from in-text to an appendix and have it stay Table 37?

Thanks!

````
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[loose,nice]{units}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{40pt}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{float}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{junicode}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})} % Style: 1(a), 1(b)
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}





\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{\textit{Model comparisons for vowel duration (ms) in EA speakers for English and Arabic /f,b/ (Analysis of Deviance Table,Type II Wald chisquare tests)}}
    \label{crosslingvowel}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
        \toprule
        & {\chi}^2 & Df & Pr(>{\chi}^2)\\
        \midrule
        voice\_target & 1.7621 & 1 & 0.1844\\
        language & 458.3895& 1 & <2e-16 ***\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} ```
````

Comment: You haven't told us so far which document class you employ, whether you run a command called `\appendix` at the start of the appendix material, and (if so) what all is run when LaTeX encounters the `\appendix` instruction. E.g., if `\appendix` changes the way that `table` (and, presumably, `figure`) environments are numbered, then moving the `table` environments to the appendix portion of the document will almost certainly affect they way in which they are numbered. In short, do please tell us more about the overall structure of your document.

Comment: Oh sorry, so the document class is article, I put the command \appendix at the start of the appendix chapter after my references but I'm not quite sure how to proceed from there; do I have to also put \renewcommand before each table or?

Answer (score 1):

The `\appendix` command, as provided by the `article` document class, does not affect the numbering of `table` and `figure` environments. Hence, you *could* manually move all `table` and `figure` material to the appendix portion. As long as the ordering of the floats is preserved, their numbers will remain the same as well.

That said, you may seriously want to look into employing the [endfloat](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat) package. If it's loaded, the material of all `figure` and `table` environments is moved to the back of the document automatically, one float per page. A nice touch is that it also inserts markers of the form "Table 37 about here" in the text where the floats would appear if the `endfloat` package weren't in use; if you don't want such markers, there's a package option that suppresses them.

Here's a reproduction of the abstract of the package's user guide:

[image]

A full MWE (minimum working example) that employs the `endfloat` package -- observe that I had to change both instances of `{\chi}^2` to `$\chi^2$` in order to make the code compilable:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{junicode}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{textfont=it,justification=raggedright}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat} % 'nolists': don't generate lists of figures and tables
\AtBeginDelayedFloats{\singlespacing}

%% (commented out remainder of preamble as it doesn't affect the MWE)
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
%%%%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[loose,nice]{units}
%\usepackage{gb4e}
%\usepackage{tipa}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{linguex}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\setlength\parindent{40pt}
%%%%%\usepackage{float} % *please* don't load the 'float' package...
%\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
%\usepackage{hanging}
%\usepackage{array}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple}
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})} % Style: 1(a), 1(b)
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % a paragraph of filler text

\begin{table}%%%%[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Model comparisons for vowel duration 
    \textnormal{(\si{\milli\second})} in EA speakers 
    for English and Arabic /f,b/ (Analysis of Deviance 
    Table, Type~II Wald chi-squared tests)}
    \label{crosslingvowel}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrc}
        \toprule
        & $\chi^2$ & Df & Pr(>$\chi^2$)\\
        \midrule
        voice\_target & 1.7621 & 1 & 0.1844\\
        language & 458.3895& 1 & $<\num[tight-spacing
]{2e-16}$\,***\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2] % another paragraph of filler text

\appendix % optional

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you!